# Realloc x86 x86_64

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, 64-bit, realloc

I have a function

```
void *srealloc(void * ptr , int size){
    void *tmp = realloc(ptr , size);
    if(tmp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"realloc of %u bytes failed", size);
        exit(1);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

My code that calls this runs fine on an x86 computer, but when I compile and run the same code on my x64 computer I get a segfault.

An example of how this is being called is:

```
line = "Some string";
buffer = (char**) srealloc (buffer,sizeof(buffer)*(++buffer_lines));
buffer[buffer_lines-1] = line;
```

When I trace through with gdb when srealloc is called on the segfaulting computer 
ptr == 0x0, size == 8

*Edit:
 The segfault occurs on:

```
void *tmp = realloc(ptr, size);
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the _pointer to pointer to char_. To be correct you should use `sizeof(char *)`. It doesn't really matter here, since the size of a pointer to one type is the same as the pointer to another type, just wanted to point this out.

Comment: buffer is a global variable: `char **buffer = NULL;`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good point, I had my code like that originally, but it got changed at one point out of frustration.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your crash, but your function also has the wrong signature, it should have the same as `realloc` itself.  `int` is not the correct type for "sizes", never use a signed type for such a purpose. In particular on modern 64 bit architectures `int` is usually only 32 bit where `size_t` is 64. Use `size_t` it is designed for things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call looks fine.  A crash in `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `calloc()` or `free()` is often a symptom of a bug elsewhere in your program, where you have written beyond the bounds of an allocated block and stomped over the housekeeping information used by the memory allocation functions.

Try running your program under a tool like Valgrind or Purify.

Comment: After running Valgrind it turns out I had a `strncpy(cp,line,strlen(line)+1)` when `cp*` was uninitialized. I assume this lead to some smashing later when I called realloc.
Valgrind was a good call.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the code calling `realloc` has a valid prototype for that function (in other words, include `stdlib.h`).

Many problems in switching from 32 to 64 bits involve the disparity between integers (the default arguments if no prototype) and pointers. While the integers may stay at 32 bits on a 64-bit platform, the pointers may be increased in size.

Since you state that the pointer is NULL and the requested size is 8, that's certainly valid use of the function. A realloc of a null pointer is effectively the same as a malloc. That's why I suspect the prototype problem.

Also make sure you're compiling *everything* on the new machine. You may strike problems if you try to link a 32-bit-compiled `srealloc` against a 64-bit-compiled client.

Comment: After running Valgrind it turns out that sending a garbage pointer to `strncpy()` was messing up my heap. This doesn't explain why my code was running on an x86 computer, but I'm glad I found the cause of this bug anyway.